# Android resources qualifier for software keys?

Tags: android, android-resources, qualifiers, nexus-4

what I need is to adjust layout for for example Nexus 4, where soft keys take up some space. The best way would be using resource qualifiers. Is there one for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can use `keyssoft` as qualifier to distinguish from other devices.

**Reference:**

[Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: Yea I just noticed that, but my Samsung Galaxy S3 (no sw keys) and Nexus 7 (sw keys) seem to both default to `values-keyssoft`, which is weird...

Comment: give it a try by using `values-keysexposed`

Comment: Still nothing. Funny thing is that they both use `values-keysexposed`

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? Would you mind trying it yourself?

Comment: @VlastoBennyLava: I don't have the s3 otherwise I would test it.by the way,first of all,check whether both of them are having permanent softkeys or not,you can confirm it by the value returned by `ViewConfiguration.hasPermanentMenuKey()`

Comment: Yea that one works as expected. S3 returns true, Nexus return false

Comment: exactly,so only one qualifier is left to test,`values-keyshidden` you may add it and hope for best to distinguish both devices.

Comment: @VlastoBennyLava: Let me know whether it worked or not.so that I can update the answer accordingly to help others as well.

Comment: Nope, now they both go to `values`. Oh well, seem I will have to do it from java which is a freaking drag...

Comment: @VlastoBennyLava: ultimately, the back key or menu key is meant to navigate.so give `values-navexposed` and `values-navhidden` a try before going through mess of handling everything by java code.

Comment: Any updates here? I have to distinguish devices with and without software buttons.

Comment: @traninho: as of now,I know only one way to solve,and that is using `ViewConfiguration.hasPermanentMenuKey()`.kindly post it back if you found some alternative way to do this.